# Fluent NHibernate and lazy load

Tags: c#, .net, session, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have some questions about about lazy loading

When I have mapped my objects, I write `.Not.LazyLoad()` everywhere in my application and it works good. But I have some problems. 
Example: I have a class `User`. It has properties `Name` and `Comments`. Mapping `Comments` in `User`:

```
HasMany(x => x.Comments).KeyColumn("UserId").Not.LazyLoad();
```

Which works good, but everywhere I load `User`, `Comments` get loaded with it, which is bad... Example of load `User`:

```
var user = session.Get<User>(1);
```

If the user has a lot of comments my application works bad...
The question is how do I enable LazyLoad if needed? Or how do I disable Lazy loading, if I don't write `.Not.LazyLoad()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer of my question. 
If don't write anywhere `.Not.LazyLoad()` and need to get `Comments`, you must to write this (get user with id=1):

```
var user = session.QueryOver<User>()
                  .Fetch(u => u.Comments)
                  .Eager
                  .List()
                  .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, what a you need.

Comment: The reason is - if something is lazy loaded ... you'll need to eager fetch it when you want it.